# Would questions about the iPad 2 Smart Cover be acceptable?

Tags: discussion, ipad

Would questions about the Smart Cover be considered on topic? It is an Apple product, but isn't really a computer hardware piece, more of just an accessory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, questions about the Smart Cover are on topic.

Comment: I'd say that any Apple hardware is on topic. If it's complex enough that people have questions about it, it's complex enough to count :)